# Application Crash on Receiving Push Notification while in Background

Tags: java, android, push-notification, distriqt

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31154): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
E/AndroidRuntime(31154):    at com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.notifications.Notifications.createNotification(Notifications.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(31154):    at com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.notifications.NotificationTask.onPostExecute(NotificationTask.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(31154):    at com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.notifications.NotificationTask.onPostExecute(NotificationTask.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(31154):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
```

If i send a Push Notification using the sample PHP code provided my app crashes while it is in the background. The Error above is spitted out. If the App is in the foreground everything works fine.

Comment: Try This                                                                                                     Right click on your project goto properties -> Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build.

Also goto android sdk manager and check that you have the android sdk build tools installed. This may not be necessary but make sure you have android build tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates you haven't included the Android Support ANE:

https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-AndroidSupport/raw/master/lib/com.distriqt.AndroidSupport.ane

Check the getting started guide for more:

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.PushNotifications#get-started